# can't install OpenAI gym

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

i am trying to install complete library of openAI gym (a toolkit for developing and comparing reinforcement learning algorithms) with help of pip. But i am getting same error again and again. i have tried everything i got on net to solve the problem but can't make it.plz help me to get a way.
here is my code---

```
mukesh@mukesh-Inspiron-5558:~/gym$ sudo pip install -e .[all]
The directory '/home/mukesh/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/mukesh/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Obtaining file:///home/mukesh/gym
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10.4 in /home/mukesh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gym==0.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.0 in /home/mukesh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gym==0.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /home/mukesh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gym==0.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pyglet>=1.2.0 in /home/mukesh/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from gym==0.7.3)
Requirement already satisfied: PyOpenGL in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from gym==0.7.3)
Collecting box2d-py (from gym==0.7.3)
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/box2d-py/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/box2d-py/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/box2d-py/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/box2d-py/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/box2d-py/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement box2d-py (from gym==0.7.3) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for box2d-py (from gym==0.7.3)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trouble installing OpenAI's gym](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870717/trouble-installing-openais-gym)

Answer (score 0):

You are behind a proxy, so you need to setup pip so that it uses your proxy. The basic format is of this form:

```
 [user:passwd@]proxy.server:port
```

For example:

```
pip --proxy http://<your proxy>:<your port> (for http)
pip --proxy https://<your proxy>:<your port> (for https)
```