# Trouble installing OpenAI's gym

Tags: python, anaconda, openai-gym

I would like to install the entire [Open AI gym](https://gym.openai.com/) package.
After (I am on a mac) `brew install cmake` , `sudo pip install gym[all]` gives me the following error

[image]

I am using anaconda 4.3.22. I am *not* in a conda virtual environment. `which python` outputs `/anaconda/bin/python`. The interpreter that anaconda uses is python 3.6.1. Just running `sudo pip gym` (which must be the minimal version) ran fine.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: You need to install swig: http://www.swig.org/ Please don't post error messages in pictures, they are unable to be searched and also mean that blind users can't help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have successfully installed gym on my mac laptop, and `brew install swig` will solve the problem.